# Huge lag when moving mouse

Tags: craft-the-world

When ever i move the mouse the game slows donw to a 1-5 fps.  when not movig mouse the game runs smooth, is this happening for many people or just me?
i know it's not finished yet, but its unplayable. Some of my friends have the game to, they have no lag when moving mouse.
**specs**
CPU I7 3630QM
GPU Nvidia GeForcer GTX 675M
RAM 4*2 GB (8GB)
say if you need more specs...

Comment: what Ghz on processor / MHz or Ghz  and V-Ram on graphics card? normally laptops graphics cards are kinda week. but if what @Philipp said is true that might be the case!

Comment: the graphic card isn't weak, im running battlefield 4 on high. I'm afraid I dont know how to see Ghz or V-ram

Comment: Looked in to it and your system should have no problem running craft the world. I was referring to "M" or Mobile graphics cards in general. But after realizing the requirements for the game any PC that was bought the last 3-4 years or so should have no problems running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs for most people. The developers are aware of it and will fix it in a later version. Such problems are to be expected in an early-access game.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue in some games by dissabling `V-Sync`